# When $x$ is given and $A$ is entrywise dominated by $B$, is $\|Ax\|\le\|Bx\|$ for some norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I have an inequality, which by intuition seems to work out, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around the details. I have two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ and a real $n$-vector $x$. The entries in $x$ are arbitrary, but the entries of $A$ and $B$ satisfy the constraint $0<|a_{ij}|\le|b_{ij}|\le1$ for each $(i,j)$.

Does it hold for **some** norm that $\|Ax\|\le\|Bx\|$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider the case where $Bx=0$ but $Ax\ne0$, e.g. when
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&1/2\\ 1&1/2},\ B=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1},\ x=\pmatrix{1\\ -1}.
$$

**Edit.** If $A,B$ are entrywise positive and $x$ is entrywise nonnegative, the answer is "yes". In this case, we have $0<Ax\le Bx$ entrywise. Hence $\|Ax\|_p\le\|Bx\|_p$ for any $p$-norm.

Comment: All matrix items are non-negative

Comment: @murtourpo95 Then why did you use absolute values (such as $|a_{ij}|$) in your question? Anyway, if $A$ and $B$ are entrywise positive, you should state that in your question. Also, is $x$ entrywise nonnegative?